# C# - Linkbutton with OnClick + href?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asplinkbutton

I do have a linkbutton and i want it to call an event on the .cs file (OnClick Event that do something).

BUT I also want to make this button moves the scroll to certain div after.

I can do:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="doSomething_Click">DoSomething!</asp:LinkButton>
```

And it does call the doSomething_Click event correctly.

OR I can do:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" href=#MainDiv>DoSomething!</asp:LinkButton>
```

And it does scroll to the "MainDiv" after clicking.

But I can't do both! **href=#MainDiv**  and   **OnClick="doSomething_Click"**

Comment: no, you can't do both as `LinkButton` utilises `onclick` event to trigger postback. if you want to do a postback then scroll down, register a js script after the postback triggered. ps. postback causes the image to reload.

Comment: i do not know much about javascript but i was reading a bit, like adding a <script></script> with something like this:

        $("button").click(function () {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(".second").offset().top
            },
        'slow');
        });
    

but how I "call" it?

Comment: Have a look at [ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_ClientScriptManager_RegisterStartupScript_System_Type_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)